# Where should we set ChangeDetection.OnPush?

Tags: angular

When I set the detectionStrategy in  my app component to be like `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.less"],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(translateService: TranslateService) {}
}
```

Does this means ALL the application in now in OnPush strategy ?

I believe this is the case, but I couldn't find an exemple that specify this

Answer (score 0):

> Does this means ALL the application in now in OnPush strategy ?

OnPush Strategy is set on a component basis; not an application wide basis.

All instances of this `app-root` component would use it.  All children of the app-root component would also use it, [as discussed here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22461).

Comment: from what I read, it is set on a component basis, but it's passed to the child, since, if a parent is on push, the child is also on push. 

If I put on app component, and everything is drawn using the app-root on the appComponent, doesn't this means that everything is in OnPushStrategy in the app ?

Comment: What did you read and where?  If that is true, then my answer is wrong.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy
This strategy applies to all child directives and cannot be overridden. but I am confused why the name directive and not component there, aren't component directive anyway ?

Comment: The main distinction between directivess and components is that components have a visual template, while directives do not.

Comment: @Bobby My original answer was wrong, I tweaked it.  Change Detection is indeed inherited by child components in the component tree.